# How to print a full array in MIPS, and sum certain integers of an array

Tags: arrays, assembly, integer, sum, mips

I am having an issue with the following code I am using for an assignment.. Note, I do not want anybody just giving me code, I am really trying to understand MIPS.  I am using the QTSpim simulator to run my MIPS code.

The following code is supposed to allow the user to enter 10 integers from the keyboard, then take those integers and sum the ones that are less than the first inputted integer (ie. 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 would sum all numbers except 10, to equal 45).  Then, the program should output the array in the order it was given.  Currently, my code is allowing the user to enter 10 integers, but then funny things happen.  It sums the numbers in a way that I cannot follow (the most common sums somehow being 0, 4, and 50), and will then only print out 4 integers for the array list (which seems to be as follows: firstNumber, secondNumber, lastNumber, 10)  I am really confused as to why this happens.  Also, for some instances of integers, it will create an infinite loop outputting 0.

I've been at this for hours, can somebody please give me some advice or pointers?
All help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
# DATA DECLARATION

    .data
request:    .asciiz "Enter an integer:\n"
sumLine:    .asciiz "The sum is: "
aList:      .asciiz "The array contains the following: \n"
return:     .asciiz "\n"
array:      .word 0
aLength:    .word 10
input:      .word 0
count:      .word 0
count2:     .word 0
count3:     .word 0
sum:        .word 0
next:       .word 0
first:      .word 0
one:        .word 1

# PROGRAM CODE

    .text
    .globl main

# PROGRAM EXECUTION

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Procedure main
# Description: Initializes registers and prints the final sum.
# parameters: $s0 = address of array, $t0 =  length
# return value: $v0 = sum
# registers to be used: $s0, $t0, $t1, $t2, $t4, $t5, $v0
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
main:

la  $s0, array          # s0 = array
lw  $t0, aLength            # t0 = aLength
lw  $t1, count          # t1 = count
lw  $t2, input          # t2 = input
lw  $t3, count2         # t3 = count2
lw  $t4, count3         # t4 = count3
lw  $t5, sum            # t5 = sum
lw  $t6, first          # t6 = first
lw  $t7, next           # t7 = next
lw  $t9, one            # t9 = one

beq $t1, $zero, readArray       # if count=0, goto readArray procedure

la  $a0, sumLine            # load line to print
li  $v0, 4              # print sum output line
syscall
lw  $a0, sum            # load sum to print
li  $v0, 1              # print sum
syscall
la  $a0, return         # load line to print
li  $v0, 4              # print return line
syscall
la  $a0, aList          # load line to print
li  $v0, 4              # print the array list line
syscall

j printArray


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Procedure readArray
# Description: Reads integers from the keyboard.
# parameters: $s0 = address of array, $t0 =  length
# return value: --------
# registers to be used: $v0, $a0, $t0, $t1, $t2, $s0
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
readArray:

beq $t1, $t0, sumSmallerThanFirst   # if t1=t0 (count = aLength) goto sum procedure
la  $a0, request            # load line to print
li  $v0, 4              # print request line
syscall
li  $v0, 5              # read integer from keyboard
syscall
sw  $v0, input          # store integer to input
lw  $t2, input          # t2 = input
sw  $t2, 0($s0)         # array[i] = t2
addi    $s0, $s0, 4         # increment array (i++)
addi    $t1, $t1, 1         # increment count (count+1)
sw  $t1, count          # store count to t1
beq $t1, $t9, store         # if t1=t9 (count = one) goto store 

j readArray

store:

lw  $t6, 0($s0)         # t6 = array[i]
sw  $t6, first          # t6 = first    

j readArray

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Procedure sumSmallerThanFirst
# Description: Sums the inputted integers if they are < the first integer.
# parameters: $s0 = address of array, $t0 =  length
# return value: ----------
# registers to be used: $s0, $t0, $t3, $t5, $t6, $t7, $t8, $0
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
sumSmallerThanFirst:

la  $s0, array
beq $t3, $t0, main          # if count=length, goto main
lw  $t7, 0($s0)         # t7 = array[i]
sw  $t7, next           # t7 = next
slt $t8, $t7, $t6           # if t7<t6, t8=1
addi    $s0, $s0, 4         # array[i++]
addi    $t3, $t3, 1         # count+1
sw  $t3, count2         # store count2 to t3

beq $t8, $zero, sumSmallerThanFirst # if t8=0, goto top sum

add $t5, $t5, $t7           # t5=t5+t6 (sum = sum + array[i]) 
sw  $t5, sum            # store sum to t5

j sumSmallerThanFirst


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Procedure printArray
# Description: Prints out the array of inputted integers.
# parameters: $s0 = address of array, $t0 =  length
# return value: -------------
# registers to be used: $v0, $t0, $t4, $t6, $s0
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
printArray:

beq $t4, $t0, Exit          # if count=length, goto Exit
lw  $t7, 0($s0)         # t7 = array[i]
sw  $t7, next           # t7 = next
lw  $a0, next           # load array[i] to print
li  $v0, 1              # print array[i]
syscall
la  $a0, return         # load line to print
li  $v0, 4              # print return line
syscall
addi    $s0, $s0, 4         # array[i++]
addi    $t4, $t4, 1         # count+1
sw  $t4, count3         # store count3 to t4

j printArray

Exit:

jr $ra                  # return
```

Comment: I haven't looked through all the code, but your array only has room for a single word (`array: .word 0`). You're probably looking to do e.g. `array: .space 40` to make room for 10 4-byte words.

Comment: I actually originally had the array set as .space 40 and it was working the same way so I changed it to how it is now with no luck. I agree it should be .space 40 though, I'll change it back.

Comment: Looking a bit further it seems that you're expecting the temporary registers to be preserved across syscalls (e.g. `readArray` uses `$t1` as its loop variable) - while they might be, I wouldn't count on it. Also, can't you get a trace of the execution or step through the code using SPIM? This should help you figure out where it goes wrong.

Comment: You should use registers $s0,..,$s7 for variables that you want to be preserved across syscalls.

Comment: After switching the t registers to the s registers, the program still runs the same way.  I also tried both types of array, .word 0 and .space 40, with no luck...  I do have SPIM and when stepping through the array it goes through the readArray sequence fine, will go through the sum sequence ten times (though giving the wrong sum), but only goes through printArray 4 times... I have no idea why.

Comment: In fact, with the temporary variables changed to saved temporaries, the readArray loop run infinitely...

Answer (score -1):

in the same position as you on what i think is the exact same assignment.

regarding the array....

if you defined array as space it'll give you some weird issues... If you define it as word. You won't have such problem. I guess this is because of the difference alignment for space and word in the kernel because I did notice the different  operation in the kernel level.

however... regarding the sum.... i keep getting ridiculous answers, mainly either 0, 1, or -1.

Comment: Yeah when I define the array as space, it won't even begin to run the program.  I really don't know where to begin debugging this thing.  It will run through the sum loop and readArray loop ten times, but only the printArray loop four times.  Really odd..

Comment: Yes, `.word` has implicit alignment in traditional MIPS assembly like MARS uses.  So use `.align 2` to align by 2^2 before `.space 40`.  But this isn't really an answer.  (I'm only seeing it because Stack Overflow decided to bump this old unanswered question for attention.)